# Find sum of a column after using binding source filter

Tags: c#, bindingsource

I am using BindingSource.Filter to get a small list of rows. Either I can find sum with `SUM(mycolumn)`
or filter using
`BindingSource.Filter="PurchaseId = '" + purchaseid + "'"`.

How to find sum of a specific column after filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution using dataset

```
inventoryDatabaseDataSet.Tables["mytable"].Compute("SUM(mycolumn)", "PurchaseId = '" + pid + "'").ToString();
```